# When using a variable inside an embed I get [object Object] returned not the value (discord.js)

Tags: discord.js

I am attempting to create a kick command for a bot and its working fine however when the bot logs the embed it doesn't display the data in the variable but [object Object]

[The Embed Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBx91.png)

My code is as following

```
exports.run = async (client, message, args) => { 

  const username =  message.mentions.members.first().user.username; //gets the first mentioned users username

  let member = message.mentions.members.first();
if(!member) return message.reply("Please mention a valid member of this server");
if(!member.kickable) return message.reply("I cannot kick this member!");

        const reason = args.slice(1).join(' ');
  
  const kickedmessage = new MessageEmbed() //embed to send to a logs channel 
    .setColor('#1773BA')
    .setTitle('User Kicked')
    .setDescription({username} + "had been kicked for " + {reason})
;
  

    client.channels.cache.get("771835493305286688").send(kickedmessage)//output the embed


member.kick(reason);
```

I am using discord.js v12

Comment: You've added extra curly brackets around `username` and `reason`,  just remove them and you'll be fine:  `.setDescription(username + "had been kicked for " + reason)`

Comment: Oh, no idea why I did that, removed them and it fixed the issue, thank you very much

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros maybe you could formulate this as an answer.

Comment: @LajosArpad Maybe but it really feels like a typo question. And look what happened to the poor guy who posted the same solution below...

Comment: It wasn't me :)

Answer (score -3):

```js
exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
    const username = message.mentions.members.first().user.username; //gets the first mentioned users username

    let member = message.mentions.members.first();
    if (!member) return message.reply("Please mention a valid member of this server");
    if (!member.kickable) return message.reply("I cannot kick this member!");

    const reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");

    const kickedmessage = new MessageEmbed() //embed to send to a logs channel
        .setColor("#1773BA")
        .setTitle("User Kicked")
        .setDescription(username + "had been kicked for " + reason);
    client.channels.cache.get("771835493305286688").send(kickedmessage); //output the embed

    member.kick(reason);
};
```